# Better Way to Change Image src While being async [angular 4]?

Tags: javascript, angular, coding-style

I have a problem which was solved by a hack and I'm looking for a better way to solve it.

What I want to do is when the user clicks input:file and selects an image it should be displayed on screen without upload (using FileReader).

The problem is, I can't reach almost anything inside Filereaders onload method (I need to reach this.image for changing image) sadly I used

```
let el = <HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector(".veik");
el.src = this.result;`
```

My code

html:

```
<input type="file" name="test" id="file" (change)="onChange($event)">
```

ts:

```
onChange($event){
    this.readThis($event);
}

ReadThis(inputValue: any) : void {
    var file:File = inputValue.target.files[0];
    var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();

    myReader.onload = function(e){
      let el = <HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector(".veik");
      el.src = this.result;
    };

    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: The way to do it in Angular would be to bind the source of the image to a property of the component, then set that value in the `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use a FileItem type to get access to the temporary file

For example: 
[1]. Change your (inputValue: any) to a  generic FileItem class, like:
 (inputValue: FileItem),

[2] Create a constant to get access to the uploaded file, like :
 const file: File = item._file

Now you can access things like file.name  , file.size etc.

Hope that helps.

Cheers